# Trying to save connections to a member vector - only saving one at a time

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, ubuntu, multiprocessing

I'm trying to write a simple server application that can take connections from several clients, and save those connections to a vector for reading by another object.

I have a class, `NetworkConnection` that's a member of another class, `Manager`. Here is my main method:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    RoutingManager *manager = new RoutingManager();
    manager->ParseInputFile("topo.txt", 10, 3, " ");

    manager->myConnection = new NetworkConnection("localhost", "7777");
    manager->myConnection->SetSocketHints();
    manager->myConnection->PopulateAddressInfo();
    manager->myConnection->BindSocket();
    manager->myConnection->ListenForConnections();

    return 0;
}
```

I've left out a lot of the details, since they're pretty similar to general socket-programming guides that you can find anywhere... the main issue is during this call:

```
int
NetworkConnection::ListenForConnections()
{
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (listen(socketFd, 15) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }
/*
    sigAction.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes    
    sigemptyset(&sigAction.sa_mask);
    sigAction.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
*/
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sigAction, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof theirAddress;
        int new_fd = accept(socketFd, (struct sockaddr *)&theirAddress, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(theirAddress.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&theirAddress),
            s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(socketFd); // child doesn't need the listener

            NodeConnection nc = NodeConnection();

            char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
            getpeername(new_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&theirAddress, &sin_size);
            struct sockaddr_in *s = (struct sockaddr_in *)&theirAddress;
            int port = ntohs(s->sin_port);
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, nc.ipstr, sizeof ipstr);

            nc.fd = new_fd;
            nc.theirAddress = theirAddress;
            nc.sin_size = sin_size;
            nc.port = port;

            newConnections.push_back(nc);
            for(vector<NodeConnection>::iterator it = newConnections.begin(); it != newConnections.end(); ++it)
            {                
                cout << "Socket ID: " << it->fd << endl;
                cout << "Their Address: " << it->ipstr << endl;
                cout << "Their Port: " << it->port << endl;
                cout << "My Size: " << newConnections.size() << endl;
                cout << "**************\n";
                //cout << "Their Port: " << (int)ntohs(it->theirAddress.sin_port) << endl;
            }
            exit(0);
        }
       // close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }
}
```

Basically, whenever I get a new connection, I want to store the details for that connection into a vector. I decided to do this by adding the details to a NodeConncetion struct:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
struct NodeConnection
{
    int fd;
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sockaddr_storage theirAddress; 
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int port;
};
```

This way, my `Manager` object can poll these connections for data.

The issue I'm having is that once a client connects, it prints the details fine. When another connects, it prints the details of that one also; however, it doesn't print the 1st connection as I would have expected, since I did a `.push_back(nc)` to save the new NodeConnection.

**Sample output:**

```
Hints set.
Binding Socket... Socket Bound!
server: waiting for connections...
server: got connection from 127.0.0.1
Socket ID: 4
Their Address: 127.0.0.1
Their Port: 33744
My Size: 1
**************
server: got connection from 127.0.0.1
Socket ID: 5
Their Address: 127.0.0.1
Their Port: 33745
My Size: 1
**************
```

---

It's possible I don't fully understand how to save off connection data .. so if I'm going about this the wrong way, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing the connection details onto your vector in the child process, after calling fork().

fork() creates a whole new process, which does not share any memory with the parent process. The child starts out an identical copy of the parent, but changes made to variables in the child are not visible in the parent and vice versa.

So the sequence you have is:

1. Parent accepts connection and creates child
2. Child adds connection data to its vector (which is empty)
3. Child prints vector (now containing one entry)
4. Child exits (and it's copy of the vector is now gone)
5. Repeat with next connection from step 1.

If you want to keep this connection data around, you need to add it to the vector in the parent process.

I notice you tagged your question 'multithreaded' - this might explain the confusion, since your program is not multithreaded, it is multiprocess. Multiple threads in the same process do share memory. I am not suggestion you change to using threads though - that brings a whole set of other issues you probably don't need.

Comment: Great explanation; thanks. I'm not sure how to listen for new connections, while also making them available to the parent thread though? Is this not possible?

Comment: It's not a parent thread, its a parent process! In most examples of this kind of server, the parent process does not need the connection, it is handled by the child. What does the parent need this for?

Comment: This is a persistent connection - so the idea was to have a class that handles all of the getting/reading new connections, and then making those available to the class that kicked off the listener. The `Manager` class could then periodically poll the newConnections vector for details.

Comment: You do not have to fork just to accept a connection. You can do it all inside a single process - you just need to make sure you always avoid blocking. Read this http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html particularly the section on select().